# Snowflake Pipe access permission denied

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Pipe execution works fine from user role using snowsql and GUI confirming no permissions issues on the pipe from the given role.

But while calling via snowpipe rest API  below error is encountered while  using same role.

```
 snowflake.ingest.error.IngestResponseError: Http Error: 403, Vender Code: 390403,

Message: Not authorized to manage the specified object. Pipe access permission denied
```

Any clue in this will be very appreciated.

Comment: Is same role being used while accessing from GUI?

Comment: What is the command being passed from Snowsql? Are you passing "role" or "r" parameter in snowsql?

Comment: Yes same role is used via gui and snowsql as well.

Answer (score 0):

The user that is used by Snowpipe REST API needs to have the role with specific permissions for the pipe assigned as default_role.
This is how default role is assigned:

```
ALTER USER <user> SET DEFAULT_ROLE=<role>;
```

where  is the role used for Snowpipe operations.

This is basically related to how RBAC works:

```
Every active user session has a “current role,” also referred to as a primary role. When a session is initiated (e.g. a user connects via JDBC/ODBC or logs in to the Snowflake web interface), the current role is determined based on the following criteria:

- If a role was specified as part of the connection and that role is a role that has already been granted to the connecting user, the specified role becomes the current role.

- If no role was specified and a default role has been set for the connecting user, that role becomes the current role.

- If no role was specified and a default role has not been set for the connecting user, the system role PUBLIC is used.
```

See for more details [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#enforcement-model-the-primary-role-and-secondary-roles)

Specifically for Snowpipe REST API usage the following permissions are required to be granted to the role:

[image]

See more details [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-gs.html#granting-access-privileges)