# Snowflake pipe - what permissions are needed for a different user to use the rest API /insertReport

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowpipe created by user A. I would then like a separate user B to check its status using the Snowflake rest API endpoint `/insertReport`.

- User A is an `ACCOUNTADMIN`
- User A created the Snowpipe.
- User A ran the following for user B's default role:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON PIPE <my pipe> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
GRANT ALL ON FUTURE PIPES IN DATABASE <my db> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
GRANT MONITOR ON DATABASE <my db> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE <my db> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
GRANT MONITOR ON SCHEMA <my schema> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <my schema> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
```

- I assumed role `USER_B_ROLE` (I don't have direct access to log in as User B) and can run the following commands and see output as expected:

```
USE ROLE USER_B_ROLE;
SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();
-- USER_B_ROLE

DESCRIBE PIPE <my pipe>;
-- created_on,name,database_name,schema_name,definition,owner,notification_channel,comment,integration,pattern,error_integration
-- 2022-01-..., ..., ...

SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS('<my db>.<my schema>.<my pipe>');
-- {"executionState":"RUNNING","pendingFileCount":0,"notificationChannelName":"arn:aws:sqs:...","numOutstandingMessagesOnChannel":0,"lastReceivedMessageTimestamp":"..."}
```

When I try using user B, using GET `https://{account}.snowflakecomputing.com/v1/data/pipes/{snowpipe}/insertReport` I receive: `{'data': None, 'code': '390403', 'message': 'Not authorized to manage the specified object. Pipe access permission denied', 'success': False, 'headers': None}`

I have checked that the public key fp and private key work since I can get a proper JWT token.

I don't think I can transfer ownership of the pipe and all future pipes of this kind as a blanket statement to user B because Terraform deploys, even those without changes, will recreate the PIPE and remove all permissions from user B - which is why I want to use `FUTURE`.

I've also tried `GRANT MONITOR EXECUTION` but that doesn't work either.

### What permissions am I missing?

---

Related documentation:

- The Snowflake rest API page does not mention permissions needed: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-apis.html#endpoint-insertreport
- Snowpipes only support `MONITOR` and `OPERATE` (and I gave them all already): https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#pipe-privileges
- This answer says that `OWNERSHIP` must be granted, but this was 2 years ago - surely there must be a way for a non-owner to check a Snowpipe ingestion report especially when I can already check them directly via SQL: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009YAcOz/how-can-i-see-pipes-using-show-pipes-or-see-their-status-with-systempipestatus-without-having-ownership-permission-to-the-pipes-need-to-debug-issues-without-the-ability-to-change-them
- This question mentions default role, but my User B is using the correct default role that I set up. [Snowflake Pipe access permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68909540/snowflake-pipe-access-permission-denied?rq=1)

Comment: I see all priv's but could not see permission  on table  to user B? Did you add them?

Comment: Are you able to run **SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS** from Snowflake UI using USER_B_ROLE? If that works, then it should also work programmatically via REST API.

Comment: @Sergiu yes, I can see run `SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS()` from the Snowflake UI using USER_B_ROLE and see results, but get the 403 in my post when trying the rest api

Comment: @Anand ah oops, I forgot to state it explicitly in the post, but I have `MONITOR` and `OPERATE` granted to the database + schema for `USER_B_ROLE`, as well as `FUTURE OPERATE+MONITOR` for all pipes in the database. I think that should cover permissions for the tables as well (?) - I thought that privileges and permissions were the same in Snowflake.

Comment: I also have `GRANT SELECT ON TABLE <ingest table> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE` and `GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE <some wh> TO ROLE USER_B_ROLE` and can run `select * from table(information_schema.copy_history(TABLE_NAME=>'db.schema.ingest_table', START_TIME=> DATEADD(hours, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())));` and see results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to call `/insertReport` by user who is not the pipe owner, if the role has `MONITOR` privilege.

**[Snowpipe: Support for Non-Pipe Owners to Call the Snowpipe REST API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-06.html#snowpipe-support-for-non-pipe-owners-to-call-the-snowpipe-rest-api):**

> **With this release, calling the public Snowpipe REST endpoints to load data and retrieve load history reports is no longer restricted to a pipe owner (i.e. the role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the pipe) or a higher role in a role hierarchy.** The following pipe privileges allow calling specific REST endpoints:

| Pipe Privilege | REST Endpoints |
| --- | --- |
| MONITOR | insertReport, loadHistoryScan |
| OPERATE | insertFiles |

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update! Glad to see this finally added, but at least for me, I'll just be sticking with the higher-ownership setup that we already implemented for now.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked with a Snowflake representative - irrespective of `MONITOR` and `OPERATE` privileges, if you want to use `/insertReport`, you *must* have `OWNERSHIP` of the pipe.

---

The permissions and features found here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-03.html#snowpipe-support-for-non-pipe-owners-to-manage-pipes-preview do not mention `/insertReport` at all. You can let a sub-role start/pause/load/read/check (via SQL) a pipe, but there are no privileges that let non-owners use `/insertReport`.